# meaning of num_units in LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am not sure what num_units means in LSTM.

https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/Understanding-LSTM-in-Tensorflow-MNIST/

Could anybody help explain what it is using the notations in the following blog?

http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Answer (score 0):

The main feature of LSTM is the state that transformed between steps.This state is the memory of LSTM that can change the effect of input and can be changed by input and previous output.`The Core Idea Behind LSTMs` section describes this concept. The size of this vector is very important.Accordingly, the dimensions of all matrices, named by `uppercase W`, is affected by the size of LSTM memory because their duty is data transformation and controlling inter-effect between memory and other values.